# PHP Get 400 error when using file_get_contents with space in URL

Tags: php, file-get-contents, php-curl

I am trying to read an external page, but the problem is the url has a space in it. For example:

www.somesite.com/test/main .html

You see a space after main. When you go to the URL via the browser the page comes up. But when I try to use PHPs file_get_contents function I get the error:

```
 failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
```

I tried curl but I get the same 400 error. Any suggestion on how to read the page? I tried using urlencode but get a 404 error.

Thanks!

Comment: can you post the real url? Or show your code?

Comment: have you tried replacing space with `%20`?

Answer (score 0):

What browser do you use?

What you can do is to check what exactly your browser sends in its request so it is accepted by server. To do that you may use addons to your browser to inspect send headers.

For the firefox give a try to these:
[Modify Headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/)
[live-http-headers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/)

once you know what exactly is send you just need to do the same with cURL that.

Most probably you fail on not sending proper user agent and the server does not serve you seeing you as a script not as a browser.

example how to set user agent:
[set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof](https://davidwalsh.name/set-user-agent-php-curl-spoof)